# My computer is very slow when swapping between applications

Tags: windows-7, memory, ssd, performance

Sometimes my computer is very low. Especially when I have 2 or 3 applications opened at the same time. I noticed when I switch from one application to another, the computer need to read on disk and it takes a lot of time...

Here is my config:

[image]

I would like to know what is the best thing I can do to upgrade my computer?

- Memory upgrade?
- Replacing my hard disk with an ssd?

About the memory, I have 4 Go installed but I see "only 2.43 Go available"... Why?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have 4 Go installed but I see "only 2.43 Go available"... Why?

It appears that both video options for that computer will seriously use a lot of memory under some conditions.

http://h10032.www1.hp.com/ctg/Manual/c01758220.pdf

```
nVIDIA GeForce 9200M GS with 512 MB of dedicated video memory (64 MB × 16 DDR2 × 4
- Up to 2303 MB video memory on computer models equipped with 4 GB of main system memory (64-bit OS

Intel Extreme Graphics - Intel GMA 4700MHD
- Up to 1759 MB of graphics subsystem memory on computer models equipped with 4096 MB of main system memory (64-bit OS)
```

> What is the best thing I can do to upgrade, Memory upgrade?

The system has two SODIMM slots for PC2-6400, 800-MHz, DDR2.  The maximum module size it will accept is 4GB.  So your best results would probably be to max out the memory.

Though without any real details I cannot say that for certain.  Take a look at your task manager.  What does the memory usage look like?

Comment: Thank you for your response. Concerning the memory slot, I think my model accept only one memory module. I opened my computer and see only one slot. My model is XU629EA dv6_3160eb. I see on hp website that the maximum memory is up to 8 Gb. Maybe I need to replace my 4Gb by a 8Gb?

Comment: @Bronzato yeah, this would be a good idea. Although...could you post a printscreen of your detailed "indice de performance"? I assume it's the hard disk which has the lowest index. Windows might swap a lot because of the low amount of memory, which would result in heavy hard disk usage, which would result in slow applications.

Comment: Thank you all. I finally bought 4Gb extra memory and my cpmputer is healthy :)